# How to eager load sub object of a sub object in Entities Framework

Tags: c#, entities

I have a Member class that has an array of MemberRoles attached to it.  Each of the MemberRoles have a Role object attached to them.  When I go to fetch my Member I know that I am going to need all the Role objects associated to the Member.  I realize that I can eager load the MemberRoles with

```
var member = context.Members.Include("MemberRoles").SingleOrDefault(....)
```

I am speculating here (because my DBA wont give me permission to run profiler, *grumble* *grumble*) but I assume that the Role associated to the MemberRole object will lazy load once I start accessing it.

How can I eager load the Role object along with the MemberRoles when I form my original query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var member = context.Members.Include("MemberRoles.Roles").SingleOrDefault(....)
```

That should eager-load MemberRoles and the associated Roles.

Comment: Sounds right.  Just as soon as I can my DBA to let me run profiler I will confirm.